# How do I express a dependency on a bean defined in an imported configuration in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, type-safety

I recently started working at a place that uses Java configuration for Spring as opposed to XML and so far I'm loving it.

My question is the following:

If we have a `@Configuration` annotated class A that imports another `@Configuration` annotated class B, what is the proper, type-safe way for a bean defined in A to depend on a bean defined in B.

Here's an example I saw in a blog (https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2012/07/spring-dependency-injection-styles-why-i-love-java-based-configuration/):

```
@Configuration
public class PartnerConfig {

    @Bean
    public PartnerService partnerService() {
        return new PartnerServiceImpl();
    }

}

@Configuration
@Import(PartnerConfig.class)
public class CashingConfig {

    @Autowired
    private PartnerConfig partnerConfig;

    @Bean
    public CashingService cashingService() {
        return new CashingServiceImpl(partnerConfig.partnerService());
    }

}
```

As a second part to my question, if I was to do the above, would Spring interpret as a bean dependency? That is, when I do

```
partnerConfig.partnerService()
```

in the example above, am I getting Spring to fetch me the `partnerService` bean, or am I just calling a regular java method and creating a new instance of the `PartherService` (which is NOT what I want, since the bean should be a singleton) ?

EDIT:
It has been suggested to use a @Qualifier. Would this work?

```
@Configuration
public class PartnerConfig {

    @Bean
    @MyCustomQualifier
    public PartnerService partnerService() {
        return new PartnerServiceImpl();
    }

}

@Configuration
@Import(PartnerConfig.class)
public class CashingConfig {

    @Bean
    public CashingService cashingService(@MyCustomQualifier PartnerService partnerService) {
        return new CashingServiceImpl(partnerService);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend giving the docs a read: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html

Refer to the section:

> @Bean Methods in @Configuration Classes

This sums it up very well.

> Typically, @Bean methods are declared within @Configuration classes. In this case, bean methods may reference other @Bean methods in the same class by calling them directly. This ensures that references between beans are strongly typed and navigable.

Also take a look at: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html

Section:

> Composing @Configuration classes

Comment: "bean methods may reference other @Bean methods in the SAME CLASS ". That was the part that worried me :)

Comment: Updated my answer to include the @Import use case. Leave it to the experts I say :).

Answer (score 1):

Just add the dependency as an argument to the `@Bean` annotated method and remove the autowiring of the configuration.

```
@Configuration
@Import(PartnerConfig.class)
public class CashingConfig {

    @Bean
    public CashingService cashingService(PartnerService partnerService) {
        return new CashingServiceImpl(partnerService);
    }

}
```

or simply autowire the `PartnerService` instead of the configuration.

```
@Configuration
@Import(PartnerConfig.class)
public class CashingConfig {

    @Autowire
    private PartnerService partnerService;

    @Bean
    public CashingService cashingService() {
        return new CashingServiceImpl(partnerService);
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that you have 2 beans called "partnerService" defined in various imported @Configuration classes, you would get a name collision. In the example I gave, this is circumvented by explicitly specifying the configuration class we want to add the bean from.

Comment: Then add a `@Qualifier` to specify which bean you want.

Comment: Aha, now that is another thing I was looking into. Could you post an example? I am looking for having the qualifier in the @Configuration class and not in the application classes. How would that work?

Comment: Also why would you have multiple configuration with a bean with the same name? Just add the `@Qualifier` to either the `@Autowired` field or the method argument.